# Need help converting C# to VB

Tags: c#, vb.net, c#-to-vb.net

I used a tool to convert C# to VB. When I run the program in VB I get the following error:

> Events cannot be declared with a delegate type that has a return type.

How do I correct this code?

**C#:**

```
using System;
[assembly: CLSCompliant(true)]

namespace Link.API
{
  public delegate decimal DecimalStringDelegate(string s);
  public delegate long OrderDelegateStatus(Order o);
  public delegate void LongDelegate(long val);
}

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace Link.API
{
  public interface TLServer
  {
    event LongDelegate newOrderCancelRequest;
    event OrderDelegateStatus newSendOrderRequest;
    string ClientName(int clientnum);
    bool SymbolSubscribed(string sym);

    Basket AllClientBasket { get; }
  }
}
```

**VB.NET:**

```vb
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System
<Assembly: CLSCompliant(True)>

Namespace Link.API
  Public Delegate Function DecimalStringDelegate(ByVal s As String) As Decimal
  Public Delegate Function OrderDelegateStatus(ByVal o As Order) As Long
  Public Delegate Sub LongDelegate(ByVal val As Long)
End Namespace

Namespace Link.API
  Public Interface Server
    Event newOrderCancelRequest As LongDelegate
    Event newSendOrderRequest As OrderDelegateStatus
    Function ClientName(ByVal clientnum As Integer) As String
    Function SymbolSubscribed(ByVal sym As String) As Boolean
    ReadOnly Property AllClientBasket() As Basket
  End Interface
End Namespace
```

Comment: If I may ask, _why_ are you converting this code? C# and VB.NET play _very_ well together, you can mix .NET classes, import from one another etc.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum "you can mix .NET classes" not in one project - it would have to be a separate assembly.

Comment: I found [this post](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?597718-Having-problem-converting-delegate-from-C-to-VB), hope it helps.

Comment: Worst comes to worst, you can compile it in C# and use a reflector program (dotPeek, dotNetReflector) to decompile it into VB.NET.  It may not be the most understandable code, but it'll work.

Answer (score 6):

As the error alludes to, VB does not support events that use a delegate with a return type.  So you can't convert the code *directly*.  One workaround would be to change the delegate to use a `ByRef` parameter instead:

```
Public Delegate Sub DecimalStringDelegate(ByVal s As String, ByRef retVal as Decimal)
Public Delegate Sub OrderDelegateStatus(ByVal o As Order, ByRef retVal As Long)
```

Comment: thank you all for the input